# Mark multiple locations on google map with google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add multiple locations on google map. I have saved the longtitude and latitude in the database. Then I retrieve it from PHP and append the the data to a Javascript function. When I hardcode the locations in Javascript, it works fine. But when I load the data with PHP it's not working. But when I check it with Firebug, it shows that the PHP values have come to the relevant places. The issue is that nothing is loading. The following is the code I up with.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("HOST","DBUSERNAME","DBPASSWORD","TABLE");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM locations");
?>
var count=0;
var my = new google.maps.LatLng(7.860661,80.674896);
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: my
}
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
    var myLatlng;
    var finallatlang=myLatlng.concat(count.toString());
    finallatlang = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $row['latitude'];?>,<?php echo $row['longtitude'];?>);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: finallatlang,
        map: map,
        title: '<?php echo $row['location_name'];?>'
    });
    count++;
<?php } ?>
mysqli_close($con);
?>
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Updated my code
        
        function initialize() {

```
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM locations");
    ?>
    //var count=0;
    <?php $count=0;?>
    var my = new google.maps.LatLng(7.860661,80.674896);
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: my
    }
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?><?php echo $count++;?>
    //var myLatlng;
    <?php $mylatlang="mylatlang";?>
    //var finallatlang=myLatlng.concat(count.toString());
    //var count=parseInt(<?php //echo $count;?>);
    //var finallatlang=myLatlng+count.toString();
    finallatlang = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(<?php echo    $row['latitude'];?>),parseFloat(<?php echo $row['longtitude'];?>));
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var latlang='<?php echo $mylatlang+$count?>';
//var latlang=Math.random();

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlang,
    map: map,
    title: '<?php echo $row['location_name'];?>'
});
//count++;
```

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Comment: You have an extra `?>` just before `mysqli_close` after I went through your code syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the final answer which i was come up with.Special thanks to Rorschach.

```
<div id="map" style="width: 1000px; height: 900px;"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("HOST","HOSTUSERNAME","HOSTPASSWORD","DATABASE");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM locations");
?>
var locations = [<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{?>

['<?php echo $row['location_name'];?>', <?php echo $row['latitude'];?>, <?php echo   $row['longtitude'];?>],

<?php }?>
];

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(6.934947,79.862308);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        myOptions);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
         }
        })
        (marker, i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your db connection(php code):

```
<?php  $con=mysql_connect("host","dbuser","dbpassword");
       mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
       $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locations");  
 ?>
```

Google map multiple markers (Javascript code) :

```
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var locations = [
                     <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))  {  ?>
                         ['marker 1',<?php echo $row["lat"] ?>,<?php echo $row["longs"] ?>, 4],
                     <?php } ?>
            ];

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
            myOptions);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;
        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
             }
            })
            (marker, i));
        }

</script>
```

Comment: No.nothing displayed.yes i checked the browser console.As i can see there the count++ is appearing twice.

Comment: Thanks.I checked it and did the way that you have mentioned.But still it's not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51255/discussion-between-rorschach-and-buddhi-eashwarage)

Comment: I updated my code.Now map is loading.But the locations are not appearing.

Comment: View source the page and check , lat longs are loading proper or not.

Comment: Yeah i checked.It's loading properly.

Comment: I don't know why its not working for you , the code which i have posted its working fine for me. anyway added on jsfiddle as well , [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/vsN55/)

Comment: Rorschach - Finally could make it work.As i feel the wrong part which i was done,i got the database locations in php for loop.So anyhow i was now done add the locations to you javascript array using while loop and retrive it via for loop in javascript.Now it works fine.I posted the final answer in following.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here (info in your 'answer', not yet in your question):

```
new google.maps.LatLng('6.936992','79.860935')
```

The LatLng constructor expects two floating point numbers, not two strings.  If it were

```
new google.maps.LatLng(6.936992,79.860935)
```

you'd be fine.  Use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to convert these values to floats:

```
finallatlang = new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(<?php echo $row['latitude'];?>),
    parseFloat(<?php echo $row['longtitude'];?>)
);
```